# QGIS' 3.x - Atlas feature not printing second pdf page

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, pdf, atlas

So, I have created a layout managed by Atlas; every layout has 2 A4 pages, one with the atlas view and another with a table based on visible objects. It works perfect when printing to paper (duplex), but when I try to export as PDF I only get the first page, so the tables are lost.
I want to print a single PDF with both pages, for every atlas object

(also, I dont mind exporting atlas objects one by one, but I need them to have both pages)

Comment: Not able to reproduce. Made a layout with two pages per feature. 39 features in my cases. Run the atlas on the layout and get unique PDF of 78 pages. Then, done postprocessing to split global PDF to two pages files (outside of QGIS).

Comment: That is certainly an option, but I have layers with 1000+ features. As online editors only accept limited sizes, it forces me to split the atlas into a lot of small pdfs. (and I cant install anything on office's pc)